# Placement of seealso-cross refs (with xindy)

Tags: indexing, xindy

Is there a way to have `seealso` cross references at the end of the index entry as the very last `\subitem`? They should look something like this:

```
Fruit
  Apples, 3
  Bananas, 4
  Oranges, 9-10
  see also Vegetables
```

By default, they are put right at the top of the index entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
.\index{Fruit!Apples}\index{Vegetables}\index{Fruit|seealso{Vegetables}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I use xindy and currently have something like this as a custom module:

```
(markup-crossref-list :class "seealso" :open "~n\subitem\seealso{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")
(define-location-class-order ("roman-page-numbers" "see" "seealso"))
```

I could, of course, change the order of the `subitem` entries by hand in the `*.ind` file since I have to edit it for optimized line and page breaks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like below code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}


.\index{Fruit!Apples}\index{Vegetables}
\index{Fruit!z@\textit{see also} Vegetables} \index{Fruit!banana}

\index{Fruit!Orange}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\index{Fruit!zzzzzzz@\textit{see also} Vegetables}`, just in case that there is a [Zig-zag vine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melodorum_leichhardtii) or [Ziziphus zizyphus](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ziziphus_zizyphus&redirect=no) in the fruit basket.

Comment: @Stephen :-) Zucchini. There is also Zyzomys, but this is no vegetable at all … ;-)

Comment: @Speravir :-)) But they could be found in a fruit basket, don't they? Maybe the owners of the basked would not want them to be there, but at least "zyz..." is a very good example! (Is there even a word (English or otherwise) after `Zyzomys` in the alphabet?)

Comment: @Stephen: In Australian fruit baskets actually. Regarding a useful word after “zyzomys” – don’t know, I’m German as you.

Comment: Caveat! In the Index "Z" might be sorted after "z"! In that case "zzzzzzz" should be replaced by "ZZZZZZZ", of course.

Comment: This also adds a page number though.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know, whether this works with `xindy`, but with `makeindex` you can do one simple thing as workaround:

Put this index entry somewhere later in the document, where you are sure, that there is a new page created. At the place, where it thematically belongs, you could then add a comment as hint.

**Edit:**

This MWE works fine here with `makeindex`. Try it out with `xindy`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel} % needed for "blindtext",
                                  % "english" is the active language
\usepackage{blindtext,lipsum,kantlipsum}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section*{Package \texttt{blindtext}}

\subsection*{English blindtext}\index{blindtext (package)!english}
%%% see below before section "kantlipsum" for
%%% \index{blindtext (package)!english|seealso{kantlipsum}}
\blindtext[1]

\subsection*{Latin blindtext}\index{blindtext (package)!latin}
%%% see below before section "kantlipsum" for
%%% \index{blindtext (package)!latin|seealso{lipsum}}
{\selectlanguage{latin}% note the grouping
\blindtext[1]}

\newpage

\index{blindtext (package)!english|seealso{kantlipsum}}
\index{blindtext (package)!latin|seealso{lipsum}}

\section*{Package \texttt{kantlipsum}}\index{kantlipsum}
%%% see below before "\printindex" for
%%% \index{kantlipsum|seealso{blindtext (package) with english option}}
\kant[123]

\section*{Package \texttt{lipsum}}\index{lipsum}
%%% see below before "\printindex" for
%%% \index{lipsum|seealso{blindtext (package) with latin option}}
{\selectlanguage{latin}% actually not needed here
\lipsum[123]}% note the grouping again

\newpage

\index{kantlipsum|seealso{blindtext (package) with english option}}
\index{lipsum|seealso{blindtext (package) with latin option}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The comments with three percent signs are these, what I called “hints”. If this does not work with `xindy`, then I’m as clueless as you.

<sub>But should there be a reason, that this is not possible with `xindy`?</sub>

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. In my real-life project (well over 200 pages long) I have all `\index` commands containing `seealso` cross references at the end of the document, right before the `\printindex` command.

Comment: @TillA.Heilmann: See my edit. If this doesn’t work with `xindy` I can’t help you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I now see that my question was probably not clear enough and has caused a misunderstanding: My cross references are neither *in* nor *for* sub entries (they always belong to the main index entry) but should only be displayed the same way as sub entries and be put *after* them. Sorry for all the work you put in.

Comment: @TillA.Heilmann: Ah, now I understand …